# Can Grease Pencil objects created with older Blender versions interact with light sources in Blender 2.83?

Tags: light, grease-pencil, 2d, compatibility

Since 2.83, [Grease Pencil objects can interact with light sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vcAxT9q78I).

[In my tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHQej.jpg), it seemed that this only applies to Grease Pencil objects that were created with Blender 2.83?

Is that correct? If not, what do I have to consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. The [Grease Pencil](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/index.html) has been rewritten from scratch and lights are only affecting *Grease Pencil Objects* created in Blender 2.83.

Quote from the official [Blog Post (5. Converting Old Files)](https://code.blender.org/2020/02/grease-pencil-refactor/):

> When you load a file, Blender tries its best to convert missing settings/features to their new equivalent (e.g. 2.7 Groups → 2.8 Collections). But sometimes there isn’t a one to one equivalent, especially if the feature has been replaced completely. **In the new system, for example, the Light Effect modifier is replaced by light objects, this case needs to be handled manually.**

---

Some new properties/data seems to be missing in the old version of the *Grease Pencil Object* thus lights can't illuminate the old strokes. However, there is a workaround:

1. Create a new *Blank* grease pencil object *(<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Grease Pencil > Blank)*
2. Replace its data-block with the old one (*Object Properties > Data-Block dropdown*)

   [image]
3. And copy all transforms (location, rotation and scale) from the old one to the newly created object *(you can use 'Copy Attributes' Add-on for that)*.

Following script does all of that in one go. Select all *appended objects* and just run the script:

[image]

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

for old_gp_obj in C.selected_objects:
    if old_gp_obj.type == 'GPENCIL':
        # Create new gp object based on the old data
        new_gp_obj = D.objects.new("{}_converted".format(old_gp_obj.name), old_gp_obj.data)
        # Copy transforms
        new_gp_obj.matrix_world = old_gp_obj.matrix_world.copy()
        # Get and link to collection
        old_gp_coll = old_gp_obj.users_collection[0]
        old_gp_coll.objects.link(new_gp_obj)
        # Hide old object in viewport
        old_gp_obj.hide_set(True)
```

*Notice that old objects are hidden after running the script.*